# Trigger for inserting values into new audit table if INSERT or UPDATE value of column X is a certain value

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

This is using Oracle SQL.

Hey all, I'm learning a lot from triggers. I have what I think is very close to the final working trigger code but there's one function missing.

I have 3 tables and a new "audit" table that logs some values from columns from each of the 3 tables if an INSERT OR UPDATE value of **column e** is "5". So when a user gives a value of 5 in the "column e" column, then the values for a, b, c, d, and e (e being the value 5)  is recorded into the audit table:

```html
CREATE TABLE grade_audit (
 columna_x VARCHAR2 (10),
 columnb_x VARCHAR2 (10),
 columnc_x NUMBER(4),
 columnd_x VARCHAR2(5),
 columne_x NUMBER(1)
);
```

Here's what I have so far with no errors returned when creating the trigger:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF columne ON book_log
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.columne = 5)
DECLARE
 columna_x VARCHAR2(15);
 columnb_x NUMBER(5);
    columnc_x VARCHAR2(20);
 columnd_x NUMBER(5);
 columne_x NUMBER(1);
BEGIN 
 SELECT  t.columna,
   t.columnb,
   te.columnc,
   te.columnd,
   b.columne
 INTO columna_x, columnb_x, columnc_x, columnd_x, columne_x
 FROM table1 t,
   table2 te,
   table3 b
 WHERE t.student_id=b.student_id
 AND te.test_id=b.test_id
 AND eval= :NEW.grade;
 INSERT INTO grade_audit
  VALUES (columna_x,columnb_x,columnc_x,columnd_x,columne_x);
END;
/
```

The trigger creates without any errors. But I am not sure if I am correct with declaring the values, and if I should be naming them something else in the new table in compared to the old table's columns.

But the values are not being recorded into the new audit table. When I try to insert or update a columne value of 5 in the book_log It gives me the error

```html
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table 234234.BOOK_LOG is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "234234.TEST_TRIGGER1", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '234234.TEST_TRIGGER1'
```

So the trigger at least know something is suppose to happen when the value of UPDATE or INSERT is 5, but I don't wan it to STOP it from happening. I just merely want those details recorded into a new table.
Inserting or updating a value of something other than 5 will create the row normally.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing-- it looks like you've replaced some table names but not others.  If we assume that your trigger is getting a mutating table error, that implies that one of `table1`, `table2`, or `table3` in your query is actually the `book_log` table on which the table is defined.  It's also hard to imagine how a `grade_audit` table possibly relates to a `book_log` table.  If you can create a minimal self-contained example that demonstrates the problem, the solution is probably relatively simple.  As it stands, though, it's hard to guess at tables and relationships.

Comment: it's because I have aliases. So I have 3 tables + the audit table.

Table 1, Table 2, and Table 3
And I want columnA from table 1, columnB  from table 2, columnC from table 2, columnD from table 3, etc.

Comment: Your query is joining `table1`, `table2`, and `table3`.  One of those tables is actually `book_log`.  You, presumably, know which one is `book_log`.  We don't.  That makes it very difficult for us to guess which table to remove from your query.  We have no idea what `book_log` and the other two tables look like which also makes it difficult to guess how to fix the query.  Finally, I am hard-pressed to imagine how a `book_log` table, which I'd assume should be storing information about books, could possibly relate to a `grade_audit` table storing information about grades.

Comment: I'm guessing that `table3` is `book_log` since its alias is `b`. Good catch by the way. @Tootally, there's nothing wrong with getting more information in a `SELECT` inside a trigger in order to use that information, but it might be better to base your `SELECT` on the values in the `old` and `new` tables.

Comment: Hi, I see you've logged in 3 hours ago. As Justin asked his question 9 hours ago I'm voting to close this question as it is unanswerable in the way you want without the answer.

Comment: kindly let us know the ddl for table3 ???